# invalid group reference when using re.sub()

Tags: python, regex, replace

I'm having troubles with re.sub. I understand from other answers that this is due to the fact I'm referencing to a capturing group that I don't have.

My question is: how do I adjust my code to have a valid group?

```
s = "hello a world today b is sunny c day"
markers = "a b c".split()
pattern = r'\b' + ' (?:\w+ )?(?:\w+ )?'.join(markers) + r'\b'
text = re.sub(pattern, r'<b>\1</b>', s)   # this gives error
```

I want to have this : `"hello <b>a  world today b is sunny c</b> day"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use `\1` replacement backreference if there are no capturing groups in the pattern. Add the capturing group to the pattern:

```
pattern = r'\b(' + ' (?:\w+ )?(?:\w+ )?'.join(markers) + r')\b' # or
              ^                                            ^
pattern = r'\b({})\b'.format(r' (?:\w+ )?(?:\w+ )?'.join(markers))
```

Or, just use the `\g<0>` to insert the whole match rather than a capturing group value (then, there is no need amending your regex):

```
text = re.sub(pattern, r'<b>\g<0></b>', s)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/81ofGa).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any groups in your regex.

`(?:...)` is a non capture group, I guess you want

```
pattern = r'\b(' + ' (?:\w+ )?(?:\w+ )?'.join(markers) + r')\b'
```

Answer (score -1):

This code can get the result what you want.I have tested.

```
import re
s = "hello a world today b is sunny c day"
pat = r'(a.*c)'
result = re.sub(pat,r'<b>\1</b>',s)
```